# Using Git I have two separate changes I am working on -- what is the best way to handle this?

Tags: git

I have checked out a large repo and begun making changes to multiple files for one complex changes; I also have a change that literally is adding a few lines to a single file. Is it better to create a branch for each change even though as I mentioned one change is very small or can I handle it all in a single branch? In the latter case, I would make the single file change first, commit it and if it is approved, push the change to the master repo.

Comment: The answer to the question is it depends on what your workflow.  You don't have to create a new branch per se, but you can certainly make the small change in a logically separate commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it better to create a branch for each change even though as I mentioned one change is very small or can I handle it all in a single branch? In the latter case, I would make the single file change first, commit it and if it is approved, push the change to the master repo.

There's very little difference between the strategies, considering that you're planning to make the small change first. If the team you're working with has any guidelines on the subject, then of course you should abide by those. For example, some teams prefer to use one branch per issue, with the branch named to reflect the issue that's being worked on. But if that's not the case, then there's little difference between the two approaches you've outlined, and you should do whichever works better for you. That said, creating and deleting branches is such a trivial operation that there's little reason not to use branches liberally to manage distinct changes.

Comment: That creating and deleting branches is trivial, no matter how many files are in the repo, I think is the "big idea" here.

Comment: @Jeff Right -- creating a branch with `git checkout -b <branchname>` takes less than 0.05s even in a repo with hundreds of files, and deleting a branch is even faster. `git` doesn't copy every file; only those files you modify are duplicated.